# Invalid node channel message when running chrome headless

Tags: amazon-ec2, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to run chrome on an amazon machine to be able to use it in a head less mode but it failed when I want to start it :

```
[root@ip-*** dev]# google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 59.0.3071.115


[root@ip-*** ec2-user]# google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 https://www.chromestatus.com
[0705/030438.715171:WARNING:audio_manager.cc(293)] Multiple instances of AudioManager detected
[0705/030438.715202:WARNING:audio_manager.cc(254)] Multiple instances of AudioManager detected
Trace/breakpoint trap
[root@ip-*** ec2-user]# [0100/000000.732486:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(41)] Invalid node channel message
```

Someone already success to run chrome on an ec2 ?

Comment: This same output with the breakpoint trap and invalid node channel message is occurring for me as well. What do you get when you run `strace google-chrome ...`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install unstable version

```
yum install google-chrome-unstable
```

Install fonts

```
yum install  \
 ipa-gothic-fonts \
 xorg-x11-fonts-100dpi \
 xorg-x11-fonts-75dpi \
 xorg-x11-utils \
 xorg-x11-fonts-cyrillic \
 xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 \
 xorg-x11-fonts-misc -y
```

Comment: The missing fonts seems to solve my error message. Thx

Comment: Yep... fonts.  I had a CentOS minimal installation, which didn't include fonts.

Comment: For ubuntu: `apt-get install fonts-ipafont-gothic xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-cyrillic`